# How to download audio clip and play in media player in android?

Tags: android

I need help with download audio clip from server and play default android media player with in same screen,How can i download audio clip  and invoke media player.How can it possible this.please help me friends

Thanks Friends..

Comment: This Means First Download the Song & Play it After Downloading. Am I Right?

Comment: @yeah Realy,i want to do this

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
private MediaPlayer mp_xmPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();

player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setDataSource("http://sdfs/MRESC/images/test/x.mp3");
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
```